# Use tomcat instead of netty for rscket

Tags: spring-boot, rsocket

I want to leverage on servlets and filters so I want to use tomcat and, in general, servlet 3.1 to handle the communication.

I tried to do the following:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-rsocket</artifactId>
<exclusions> 
    <exclusion> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId> 
    </exclusion> 
</exclusions>
```

It works bringing up a tomcat but I lost the endpoint!
Here's what I do to register it:

```
spring.rsocket.server:
   transport: websocket
   mapping-path: /topics
```

and:

```
@Configuration
 public class RSocketConfig {

@Bean
public Mono<RSocketRequester> rSocketRequester(
        RSocketStrategies rSocketStrategies,
        RSocketProperties rSocketProps) {
    return RSocketRequester.builder()
            .rsocketStrategies(rSocketStrategies)
            .connectWebSocket(getURI(rSocketProps));
}

private URI getURI(RSocketProperties rSocketProps) {
    return URI.create(String.format("ws://localhost:%d%s", 
            rSocketProps.getServer().getPort(), rSocketProps.getServer().getMappingPath()));
}
```